# Commenting in IntelliJ for html files gives {# instead of <!--

Tags: intellij-idea, ionic-framework

I have this weird situation in intellij where whenever I try to comment a region in my html file, instead of making the  like it used to do, it now makes "{# .. #}" I tried looking online for how to resolve this but did not run across a solution. I'm sure it's some simple configuration. Do you know where I might be able to fix this?

Add'l Details:
- I'm running IntelliJ 15.0.1 on OSX Yosemite.
- It works on my other projects but doesn't work on my projects started with ionic.

Answer (score 1):

Check your *File | Settings | Editor | File Types* settings (*IntelliJ IDEA | Preferences | Editor | File Types* on OSX). Likely you have the `*.html` pattern mapped to a different file type than HTML. 
If that is indeed the problem, just add the `*.html` pattern to the HTML file type and it will pop up a dialog telling where it is assigned now and asking if you want to reassign. Probably you have it assigned to something like the template languages Django & Jinja2 (for Python) or Twig (for PHP).

Comment: Hey thanks Bas! I'm having a bit of trouble finding that section in the menu. I'm running IntelliJ v15.0.1 on OSX Yosemite. I'll keep looking for that section but it sounds like that might be it. Another note is that it works on my other projects but doesn't work on my projects started with ionic.

Comment: I added some directions for OSX in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I found it but it looks like the file type was already assigned properly. I wonder if it's some other overriding setting similar to what  '.editorconfig' does...

Comment: Hmm, too bad.  Maybe it is something else then. Do you use a 3rd party plugin for ionic support?

Comment: no I just installed it and then tried to use intellij to edit the folder. I guess I'll just use sublime or something to do html manipulation. it just a bit annoying. Thanks for looking into it.